# SSRS how to format memo field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm pulling data from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database and one of the fields is a memo field.

When the data is displayed it comes out in the format DATE/USER/then the message. There is a line break and this repeats. For example:

```
30/10/2013 11:34 TRACEY : order Created
30/10/2013 11:38 AUTO : order Authorised
30/10/2013 11:40 TRACEY : order Issued
30/10/2013 11:41 TRACEY : order processed
```

I don't have an control in changing SQL database tables/fields.

I want to be able to format this ugly block of text but really struggling to find a solution - for display in SSRS report. Is there any way I can add a space between each line? Or strip out certain words or complete lines based on some specific parameter?

I just don;t seem to be enable control formatting of memo fields. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the query that is pulling this data from data source. You can use CHAR(13) to send next record in next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function (in the report' declaration) which will perform the formatting, but this is not the simple task. After this you can call this function and receive  a formatted text.
Samples of this you can find in the following articles:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx